# javascript issue in chrome

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following code in javascript
I am storing a php array in a javascript array below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var name=new Array();
    <?php
        for($i=0;$i<count($ids); $i++)
            {
                echo "name[$i]='".$name[$i]."';";
            }
    ?>

</script>
```

When i alert name[1], in firefox I am able to see the value of name[1], but when i run the code in chrome i get undefined in the alert box.

How can i solve this.
Do I have to change the way I am storing the array or do I have to do something else.

Comment: Check the view source, and use the code there in your question. You can check the javascript console for errors in chrome with ctrl+shift+j. You can also replace the whole thing with `var name = <?php echo json_encode($ids); ?>;`

Comment: @epoch. Atleast the answer must be right to accept it. If it is blindly accepted, others having the same issue will be misguided into trying it out.

Comment: @Esailija. Its partly working. Now i don't get an undefined alert but i don't get a proper alert either. For eg: In firefox I am getting an alert of "Madhya Pradesh" and in Chrome i just get "a"

Comment: @Shatir Can you show the code with the `alert()` call as well please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're committing a great sin in declaring your variable:

- It's a global, which is bad practice.
- it's name is `name`, which is a reserved keyword in chrome, just open console and type `for (n in window){if (n === 'name'){console.log(true)}}`, it'll log true
- don't use `new Array();`, use `[]`

on php front: either use the double quotes consistently, or use single quotes (but that's just my personal preference):

```
echo "name[$i]='{$name[$i]}';";
echo 'name['.$i.']="'.$name[$i].'";';
```

Like the way you place the curly's, though... :-P